# Neo4j - Delete 2 related nodes with all of their relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to deletes 2 related nodes with all of their relationship.

This is the query that I've been trying to do that:

```
match  (picture:Picture) where picture.id='101531146106623881437036830' 
optional match ()-[r]- picture-[:UPLOADED_TO]-(facebook:Facebook)-[rf]-()     
with r,rf,picture,facebook,picture.id as id     
delete r,rf,picture,facebook
return id
```

Can't seem to get it right for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is not working because you can't delete picture, a relation is still linked to it.

#### Let's check the query and explain the error

```
match  (picture:Picture) where picture.id='101531146106623881437036830'
```

Ok you match the picture node, everything is fine here

```
optional match ()-[r]- picture-[:UPLOADED_TO]-(facebook:Facebook)-[rf]-()
```

Using optional match is a choice, but the problem here is that you didn't set a variable for `UPLOADED_TO`, so this relation is seen by the query, but no references are made.

```
with r,rf,picture,facebook,picture.id as id
```

Here you push your references to the delete part (it's not needed in fact, only usefull pour aliases here)

```
delete r,rf,picture,facebook
return id
```

And finally you delete what you wanted to delete, but here you get an error "Can't delete node because it has relationships" or something like that. It's because `UPLOADED_TO` relation still exists.

#### How to fix?

Simply add a reference to `UPLOADED_TO`relation to delete it.

```
match  (picture:Picture) where picture.id='101531146106623881437036830' 
optional match ()-[r]- picture-[r2:UPLOADED_TO]-(facebook:Facebook)-[rf]-()     
with r2,r,rf,picture,facebook,picture.id as id     
delete r2,r,rf,picture,facebook
return id
```

MicTech's answer should work too, but I wanted to clarify your mistake to avoid doing it again ;)

Answer (score 2):

What about this

```
MATCH ()-[r]-(p:Picture {id:'101531146106623881437036830'})-[:UPLOADED_TO]-(fb:Facebook)-[rf]-()
DELETE r, p, fb, r
```